# MongoDB object pointing

Tags: database-design, mongodb, python

I am doing an web app and i have a doubt. I need to get a value of a MongoDb JSON? object. I post my code..

`import pymongo 
try:
        conn =pymongo.MongoClient('localhost')
        print('Conexion realizada:')
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
        print('No se ha podido realizar la conexion: %s' % e)
db = conn.test
coll = db.puntos
print(list(coll.oxigeno.find())) <-- I want to print the Oxigeno value of the Objct`

Thanks you so much

Comment: Might fit better to stackoverflow site

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a dude"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want when you say you want to print the Oxigeno value of the object, but to print the values of oxigeno for the documents in the query results, do

```
for doc in coll.find():      # .find() returns cursor which is meant for iteration
    print(doc["oxigeno"])    # doc is a python dictionary representing the returned BSON document
```